# Finite amount of sets of natural numbers cover the reals?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, real-numbers

Suppose you have sets such that$ N = \{(−n, n) : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. Why can't a finite amount of these sets cover the real numbers?

My solution: If there were a finite number of these sets, then there exists a finite lower bound and finite upper bound which we will call $-M $ and $M$. Thus, $(-M - 1)$ and $(M + 1)$, are real numbers, which are not contained in any of these sets. Thus, a finite amount of these sets cannot cover the reals.

Correct, incorrect, better or more efficient way to do this?

Comment: If I read your question correctly, your answer is correct. But you have two $N$'s in your first sentence that can't mean the same thing, so there's some ambiguity.. And you might say how you determine $M$ from the finite list.

Comment: sorry, its supposed to be "element of the natural numbers". I'll fix that

Comment: Am I understanding "cover" correctly? It would only cover the reals if the union of all these sets N had an infimum and supremum that are negative and positive infinity respectively?